# VBA Loop PivotTable

Tags: excel, vba, loops, pivot

I use the following code to loop through each country in a PivotTable:

```
Sub AutoLoop()

Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim Country As PivotItem

For Each Country In PT.PivotFields("Country Name").PivotItems

MsgBox PT.PageFields("Country Name").DataRange.Value

Next Country

End Sub
```

However the message box always returns the value 'All' for each of the countries, as that is the default selection in the 'Country Name' PageField. It does not loop through and give the country name for each of the countries. If I manually select a country, then the message box will always return that country. How do I get the MsgBox code to factor in the loop?

In essence, what I need is for the DataRange of the PageField to change and show the current country, rather than just have the countries loop through with no change to the DataRange in the PivotTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be a bit off in how I understand your aim, but if I'm correct about you trying to loop over each country, change the pivot table's page field to show that country, and output the country's name to a message box, you are a bit far off.

See how you loop through `Country`? You're not using it inside the loop. You should use it. See my code below.

```
Sub AutoLoop()

Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim Country As PivotItem

For Each Country In PT.PivotFields("Country").PivotItems
    PT.PivotFields("Country").ClearAllFilters
    PT.PivotFields("Country").CurrentPage = Country.Name
    MsgBox Country.Name
Next Country

End Sub
```

This is tried and tested (again, if I understood you correctly). What it does is clear the filter on every iteration (just to be safe), change the filter to the current `Country` and output the name of that `Country` to a message box.

See following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: You understood me correctly, @Nanashi, and that works! Thanks